# Why does an element positioned absolutely outside the body cause a horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: css, position, overflow, absolute

From the W3C Website

> In the absolute positioning model, a box is explicitly offset with respect to its containing block. **It is removed from the normal flow entirely (it has no impact on later siblings).**

But when I position an element absolutely, and it's overflowing outside of the view, it creates a horizontal scrollbar. Why? Am I understanding the specs wrong?

And is there a way to prevent this scrollbar from appearing without using `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body element?

Comment: There are many answers - http://stackoverflow.com/q/36531708/483779

Comment: _[…]It has no impact on later siblings_, this is correct, but if it's overflowing outside the body, your browser default behaviour will be to add scrollbars to help reach this element. So I'd guess the answer is **no**, there's no way to prevent the scrollbars without `overflow-x: hidden;` (but, this could be added to any container, not necessarily the `body`)

Comment: Yes, there is. Position it absolutely (no left or right values) but use a CSS transform to push it off the page. - https://jsfiddle.net/wss6Lsy0/

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried using your transform solution but it still adds a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what’s your goal, one option is to use an absolutely positioned wrapper with `overflow: hidden; width: 100%` and then position your elements (e. g. shadows on each side of the centered container wrapping the entire page contents) inside *this wrapper*.

Comment: I went with the `overflow-x: hidden;` solution in combination with media query breakpoints. That being said I cannot accept this as an answer to my initial question, which was asking for a solution that **doesn't** use `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Fwiw, in your question you said about the `BODY` element (`overflow: hidden` for `BODY` is indeed generally harmful) while my answer suggests using `overflow: hidden` for a _separate_ element (which is typically harmless if used for purely decorative purposes), but since you haven’t provided details about your specific task (feel free to do this now or later), we cannot say for sure what is applicable in your case.