# when css position sticky stops sticking

Tags: css, sticky, boundary

I was wondering why `position: sticky` works for some x-axis-scrolling, but once you scroll past the initial width of the screen width, your 'sticky div', stops sticking.

In this example, I have a left-side-bar that sticks to the left (please note that I cannot use `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`, because in my actual project both the left-div and the right-div need to scroll up and down along the y-axis, hence we only want left-side-sticking)

is there an additional CSS parameter I can define, such as

```
left-sticky-distance=999999%
```

or something like that?

some test code illustrating is below

```
    <html>


    <body>

    <div style='
    position:sticky;
    z-index:1;
    left:0;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    opacity:0.8;'
    >

    </div>

      <div style='position: absolute; top: 10; left: 10; width: 200; height:50px; background-color: blue'>B</div>
      <div style='position: absolute; top: 10; left: 110; width: 200; height:50px; background-color: blue'>C</div>
      <div style='position: absolute; top: 10; left: 210; width: 200; height:50px; background-color: blue'>D</div>
    </body>
    <html>
```

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle or something ?

Comment: Or a Stack Overflow snippet

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45530506 answers the problem.

Once the "sticky div" reaches the edge of the screen, it is at the end of the viewport of the parent element. This causes the sticky element to stop and stay at the end of parent's viewport. This code pen provides an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JOOBxg

```css
#parent{
      width: 1000px;
      height: 1000px;
      background-color: red;
}
#child{
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: blue;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
}
body{  
      width: 3000px;
      height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of using height: 1000px; one should use height: auto; to the parent element it will automatically adjust its height to allow its content to be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 47):

After I add the `height: auto;` into body's CSS attributes as below, this auto-hiding problem is fixed.

```
body {
    background: #fff;
    color: #444;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    height: auto;
}
```

Hope it will be helpful to you. :)

Comment: Setting it to body did't help in my case. But setting `height:auto` to first page-wrapper did. This issue related with overflow: hidden | scroll | auto . More info at https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: This solved my issue. But I don't know how it fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: It would be amazing if someone could edit this answer to explain why this works?

Comment: `min-height : 100vh;` did the trick. Thanks !

Comment: Same issue. I had to remove "height:100%".

Answer (score 1):

What i've just realized is that is stops sticking because you haven't captured an overflow. if you've specified an overflow: hidden;, then check that all content within that axis fits perfectly on all screen sizes and if not then make the necessary adjustments to make the content fit. This also happens when you have specified the height of a div and the content overflows past that height in a certain screen sizes.

I hope this helps anyone that made the same mistake i did.