# gt table - freeze columns (or make them more readable)

Tags: r, data-visualization, gt

I am creating a table using the **gt** package in R Studio, and I can't figure out a graceful way to make the columns more readable for tables with many rows.

Take the following code:

```
gt::sp500 %>% slice(1:100) %>%
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(date)) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  gt::gt(rowname_col = "date")
```

As you see below, the columns are visible through the first ~35 rows...
[image]

But once you move beyond that, I find myself having to scroll up to remember which column is high and which is low, and whether adjusted close is in the 6th column or the 4th. Is there a way to either freeze those columns in place as you scroll (using the gt package), or easily repeat the column headers after each group (without messing with the underlying data)?

[image]

Comment: I believe at the moment there is no function in {gt} that allows for repeating headers easily. This issue on the topic might be helpful: https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/194. The {kable} package does a better job of repeating headers if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to overflow property set in the outer div and .cell-output-display. Just unset them and it works. Here is a working example:

```
gt::sp500 %>% slice(1:100) %>%
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(date)) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  gt::gt(id="two",rowname_col = "date") %>% opt_css(
    css = "
    .cell-output-display {
      overflow-x: unset !important;
    }
    div#two {
      overflow-x: unset !important;
      overflow-y: unset !important;
    }
    #two .gt_col_heading {
      position: sticky !important;
      top: 0 !important;
    }
    ")
```

All credits go to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74018478) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45530235).