# r - Fixed headers with scrollbar with gt

Tags: r, gt

I have a large dataset to present in an app with a gt table and need to have fixed headers with a vertical scrollbar applied to the table and not to the container in which the table is placed as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64284277/gt-table-freeze-columns-or-make-them-more-readable).

I tried to add css code based on [this article](https://vembarrajan.medium.com/html-css-tricks-scroll-able-table-body-tbody-d23182ae0fbc) in which the last example shows a table with fixed headers but my result is a table where the body columns are not aligned with the header columns. I am also not sure what the minimal css required to achieve the desired result is.

```r
library(tibble)
library(gt)

tibble(mtcars) %>% gt(id = "two") %>%
  tab_options(
    data_row.padding = px(3),
    column_labels.background.color = "blue"
  ) %>%
  opt_css(
    css = "
    #two {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    #two tbody{
      display:block;
      overflow-y: auto;
      height: 500px;
    }
    
    #two thead tr {
       display: block;
    }
    
    #two th, #two td {
      padding: 5px;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    "
  )
```

[Fixed headers, scrollbar but headers ignore the space the scrollbar takes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWdg0.png)