# Position Sticky with nextjs

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, sticky

im new to sticky and i didn't use it before, so i copy & paste some codes (about sticky sidebar) into my project but it doesn't work.

```
<Layout title="Books">
      <div className="container w-100 row">
        <div className="sticky-top col-sm-3">
          <Filter />
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-9 ">
          <Books />
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </Layout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to tell without a live preview. But before using `position:` `sticky;`  there are few things to remember:

1. `position:` `sticky` won't work if ancestor element has one of the following values for the `overflow` property: `hidden`, `scroll`, or `auto`
2. You must specify a threshold with at least one of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, or `left` for sticky positioning to behave as expected.

Comment: Thank You so much, but i watched after those properties and everything is OK..  But i read something about height of element and ancestors, so i think there is a problem in height

Comment: can you provide a snippet or live example?

Comment: Thank you again and again, i watched very carefully and found that i was added ```overflow-x : hidden ``` to body, then i removed it so its work just perfectly

Comment: you are very much welcome! Happy coding!