How to create horizontal scrolling div without overflow-y hiding elements?
This seems crazy but I cannot find an example of horizontal scrolling without overflow-y hiding content.
Is there a way to setup a horizontally scrolling div where absolutely positioned elements (dropdowns) can be visible?
Working example: https://codepen.io/BRacicot/pen/WLQXXE
.chips {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}



You are seeing this issue because you are using position absolute on .dropdown element. You can check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531708/why-does-position-absolute-make-page-to-overflow to know that why absolute causing overflow.

You need to make parent element for .chips element and set the height of the scrollable section.
And then you would set the height to the .chips element to make it visible for dropdowns.


<div class="content-wrapper" style="height: 47px;>
            <div class="chips" style="height: 62px;>
                <div class="chip large">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <div class="chip select">
                    <button type="button">click</button>
                    <div class="dropdown active">
                        a whole bunch of visible content
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="chip large">Blog</a>
                <a class="chip large">In the news</a>
                <a class="chip large">Press releases</a>
                <a class="chip large">Case studies</a>
                <a class="chip large">Video</a>
            </div>
        </div>



And then you need to set z-index for .dropdown to make it visible.
Here are the working example on my side

Hi Roman, I see your point. Its not a solution but a good fallback if this truly is not possible.

Ah, Make sense what you mean.
Then we need to set the .select class position: unset; and set the position to dropdown position to absolute with proper top property

https://i.sstatic.net/yqnbY.jpg
Check this one

Reason on tailwindcss is above, direct parent doesn't have position: relative; but have deeper level parent have postion: relative; that's why img element showing in tailwind example

Maybe could you send me an message on Upwork and discuss in more detail?

Thanks Roman, you helped me see that relative children become relative to the wrapper div and thus hidden on y axis. Sneaky indeed.

You can give height to the div so that your div does not scroll(vertically) along with horizontal scrolling.
after giving height to your div, You need to add  vertical-scroll to hidden.
overflow-y: hidden;
height:20px;
overflow-x: auto;

